# Angular image gallery with ng repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, image-gallery

I want to change the following image from a thumbnail.

Here is the code:

```
<input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="{{$index+1}}" ng-model="g" ng-repeat="gallery in Blog.GalleryImageList"/>
<label for="{{$index+1}}" ng-model="g">
  <img ng-repeat="gallery in Blog.GalleryImageList" ng-src="{{gallery}}" width="100" height="50" class="col-md-2"/>
</label>
<img ng-repeat="gallery in Blog.GalleryImageList" ng-src="{{gallery}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded ImgSize"/>
```

Comment: can you please provide some more explanations like what are you trying to do?

Comment: @OSt I have added image slider gallery and want to add images dynamically in that using ng-repeat. You can refer from here "http://codepen.io/MariamMassadeh/pen/fkAKF" what I want to do.

Comment: You should use a single ng-repeat with multiple elements, rather than many ng-repeat. You should almost certainly use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` instead of a regular ng-repeat too, as it would appear that the gallery expects no wrapping elements

Comment: @haxxxton: thank you, your suggestion works. :-)